# How to add Count() method on my content type in orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

I have a content type named "News" with `Title`, `Body`, `Autoroute` and a  `TextField`. I have 2 problems:

1. To Count value of content items by text field named Author (can't use taxonomy terms).
2. To  Count total sum of content items by Date (from 2017-01-01  to 2017-12-31)

Now, I want to add a Count() method on my content type, so I can filter, sort and use Projection.

How can I do this?
Or do you have a better method for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Orchards `ISearchService` for this. Just [add your ContentType to a search index](https://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Search-and-indexing/) (you can have multiple indices) and check the fields you want to include, like `created` and `author`.

Then you can search like this and use the `TotalItemCount` property of the `ISearchService`:

```cs
var pager = new Pager(this.OrchardServices.WorkContext.CurrentSite, page, pageSize);
var searchSettingsPart = this.OrchardServices.WorkContext.CurrentSite.As<SearchSettingsPart>();

// Orchard.Search.Services.ISearchService
var searchHits = this.searchService.Search.Query(
    searchText,
    pager.Page,
    pager.PageSize,
    searchSettingsPart.FilterCulture,
    searchSettingsPart.SearchIndex,
    searchSettingsPart.GetSearchFields(searchSettingsPart.SearchIndex),
    searchHit => searchHit);

var count = searchHits.TotalItemCount;
```

As far as the description of your ContentType goes, I think Orchard already provides all the necessary filters for a projection.
If you need something special you'd need to implement your own [FilterProvider](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/1.10.2/src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Projections/Services/IFilterProvider.cs). The [ContentTypesFilter](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/1.10.2/src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Projections/Providers/Filters/ContentTypesFilter.cs) is a good example on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks Xceno ,  Need I to write  own Search module to use the TotalItemCount property of the ISearchService ? How can I do this?

Comment: @jiangyo4 You can just use orchards built in search module. But it may depend on your situation. Where exactly do you need that TotalItemCount?
What exactly are you trying to build?

Comment: I would like to display statistics like this: 1."Peter" : 20posts; 2."Linda" : 15posts; 3."Mary" : 10posts; ....by text field named Author,Because,Author dont need to register and  sign in.so, I don't know Author's name.

Comment: @ Xceno, I forgot,This is  a  enterprise intranet  News System.

Comment: @ Xceno   Everyone  in  enterprise  all  has  a Shared account in  intranet